# How to reload(or Initialize) google maps and events using ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, google-maps

I have google map  `funtion initialize ();` and it has event like addListener, addDomListener which are for opening and closing infowindows when I mouseover and mouseout specific DOM. And I'm using ajax to initialize google map.

```
$("#myButton").click(function(){   
   $.ajax({
    url: "/map/mappage",
    type: 'GET',
    data: data,
    success: function(data){
      //I replaced data
      initialize();
    }

  });  

});
```

But when I do this, Initializing works fine, but events are not initialized. I mean, two infowindow is opened. So, I put `google.maps.event.clearInstanceListeners(infowindow);` before I initialize the map to remove previous events, but it does not working. Page falls in infinite loop.

What I want to do is when I click #myButton, reloading(or initializing) whole map with updated(initialized) events.

I edited my question from here -----My function looks like

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var map = null; 


   //google map
   function initialize() {
     map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),mapOptions);
      $.get("/map/from_hasuk", function(data, status){
         for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){

           var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
           var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(data[i].lat, data[i].lng); 
           var labelKind = ["label1","label2" ,"label3"];
           labelKind = shuffle(labelKind);
           var markerLabel = labelKind[0];

           var marker = new MarkerWithLabel({  
              position: latlng,
              map: map,
              <% if 'data[i].price_from' != 'data[i].price_to' %>
              labelContent: data[i].price_from+'~'+data[i].price_to,
                <% else %>
              labelContent: data[i].price_from,
                <% end %>    
              labelAnchor: new google.maps.Point(27, 25),
              labelClass: markerLabel,
              icon: d_marker,
              url: "/hasuk_houses/" +  data_id
           });
           marker.setValues({type: "point", id: i});
           var data_id = data[i].id;
           var str_id = data_id.toString();
           var hash_id = "a" +str_id;
           markerObj = document.getElementById(hash_id);

    //event 
    var listener1 = google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                  var markerUrl = this.url;
                  window.open(markerUrl, "_blank");
              });
    // infowindow open 
    var listener2 = google.maps.event.addListener(marker,'mouseover', (function(marker,contentString,infoWindow){ 
          return function() {
             infoWindow.setContent(contentString);
             infoWindow.open(map,marker);
          }; // function end
        })(marker,contentString,infoWindow));

    // infowindow close
    var listener3 =  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseout', (function(infoWindow) {
          return function()  {
            infoWindow.close();
          };
         })(infoWindow));

     // listbox infowindow open
    var listener4 = google.maps.event.addDomListener(markerObj, 'mouseover', (function(marker, contentString, infoWindow) {
          return function() {
            infoWindow.setContent(contentString);
            infoWindow.open(map,marker);
          }; // function end
        })(marker,contentString,infoWindow));

     // listbox infowindow close
    var listener5 = google.maps.event.addDomListener(markerObj, 'mouseout', (function(infoWindow) {
           return function() {
             infoWindow.close();
           }; // function end
          })(infoWindow));


     // marker occur moving
     var listener6 = google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', (function(str_id) {
            return function() {
              var result_id = "#" + "a" + str_id;

              $(document).ready(function() {        $('.listbox').animate({scrollTop:$(result_id).position().top}, 300);
              });

            };
          })(str_id));


    // listbox color
      var listener7 = google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', (function(str_id) {
          return function() { 
            var result_id = "#" + "a" + str_id;
            $(document).ready(function() {
              $(result_id).css("background-color","rgba(45, 205, 113, 0.5)");              
            });
           };
         })(str_id));


    // listbox remove color
      var listener8 = google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseout', (function(str_id) {
          return function() {
             var result_id = "#" + "a" + str_id;
             $(document).ready(function() {
               $(result_id).css("background-color","transparent");
             });
          };
        })(str_id));

    var listener9 = google.maps.event.addListener(infoWindow, 'domready', function() {

        // Reference to the DIV that wraps the bottom of infowindow
        var iwOuter = $('.gm-style-iw');

        /* Since this div is in a position prior to .gm-div style-iw.
         * We use jQuery and create a iwBackground variable,
         * and took advantage of the existing reference .gm-style-iw for the previous div with .prev().
        */
        var iwBackground = iwOuter.prev();

          var iwBackground = iwOuter.prev();

       // Remove the background shadow DIV
       iwBackground.children(':nth-child(2)').css({'display' : 'none'});

       // Remove the white background DIV
       iwBackground.children(':nth-child(4)').css({'display' : 'none'});

       var iwCloseBtn = iwOuter.next();
       iwCloseBtn.css({'display': 'none'});


       iwBackground.children(':nth-child(3)').find('div').children().css({'box-shadow' : 'none', 'border': '1px solid #ECF0F1', 'border-top' : 'transparent', 'z-index' : '1'});
      });

                     marker.setMap(map);
              } // for end
           }); //$.get end
          } //google map end
          google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);


        </script>
```

These are on my `<head>` and my ajax is on the end of my `mappage.html.erb`

Comment: What does the `initialize` function look like?  Add that to your question.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: @duncan Sorry for my scarce question. I updated my function initialize() if you don't mind, please see it.

Comment: @honk-chank Where in your code were you doing `clearInstanceListeners`?

Comment: @duncan I was putting that on my `ajax succecss function`, but it's not working.

Comment: The problem is that the variable `marker` that you would have called `clearInstanceListeners` on, was just a local variable to that function. So each time you called `initialize`, that's created as a new variable; the clearInstanceListeners wouldn't have been doing anything.  Make `marker` a global variable, then it might work.